# Convert string into array perl

Tags: arrays, perl, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a script which takes headers of a multi-fasta file and pushes them into an array. Then I want to loop through this array to find a specific pattern and perform some commands.

```
open(FH, '<', $ref_seq) or die $!;
while(<FH>){

    $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    if(m/^>([^\s]+)/){
        $ref_header = $1;
        print "$ref_header\n";
        chomp $header;
        if($1 eq $header){
            $ref_header = $header;
            #print "header is $ref_header\n";
        } 
    } 
}
```

This code prints headers like

```
chr1
chr2
chr3
```

How can I push these headers into an array?

I tried following code, but it splits individual letters, instead of `$header_array[0]` being `chr1`

```
@header_array = split(/\n*/, $ref_header);
            print ("Here's the first element $header_array[0]");
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorten the code as shown below, removing some extra statements, and use `push`. You can combine `push` and the pattern match:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;

my $in_file = shift;
my @headers;

open my $in_fh, '<', $in_file or croak "cannot open $in_file: $!";
while ( <$in_fh> ) {
    push @headers, />(\S+)/;
}
close $in_fh or croak "cannot close $in_file: $!";

print "@headers";

# Now, loop through headers and select the ones you need, for example:

for my $header ( @headers ) {
    if ( $header =~ /foo/ ) {
        # do something
    }
}
```

A few suggestion on fixing your original code are below:

```
# Always use strict and use warnings.

# Remove extra parens and make the error message more informative:
open(FH, '<', $ref_seq) or die $!;
while(<FH>){

    $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    # [^\s] is simply \S:
    if(m/^>([^\s]+)/){
        $ref_header = $1;
        print "$ref_header\n";
        # where is $header coming from?
        chomp $header;
        # if the condition is satisfied, this assignment does not make sense:
        # $ref_header is already the same as $header:
        if($1 eq $header){
            $ref_header = $header;
            #print "header is $ref_header\n";
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [push](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push):

```
push @header_array, $ref_header;
```